# How to use reference variables by character string in a formula?

Tags: r, string, formula, paste, names

In the minimal example below, I am trying to use the values of a character string `vars` in a regression formula. However, I am only able to pass the string of variable names ("v2+v3+v4") to the formula, not the real meaning of this string (e.g., "v2" is dat$v2).

I know there are better ways to run the regression (e.g., `lm(v1 ~ v2 + v3 + v4, data=dat)`). My situation is more complex, and I am trying to figure out how to use a character string in a formula. Any thoughts?

**Updated below code**

```
# minimal example 
# create data frame
v1 <- rnorm(10)
v2 <- sample(c(0,1), 10, replace=TRUE)
v3 <- rnorm(10)
v4 <- rnorm(10)
dat <- cbind(v1, v2, v3, v4)
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)

# create objects of column names
c.2 <- colnames(dat)[2]
c.3 <- colnames(dat)[3]
c.4 <- colnames(dat)[4]

# shortcut to get to the type of object my full code produces
vars <- paste(c.2, c.3, c.4, sep="+")

### TRYING TO SOLVE FROM THIS POINT:
print(vars)
# [1] "v2+v3+v4"

# use vars in regression
regression <- paste0("v1", " ~ ", vars)
m1 <- lm(as.formula(regression), data=dat)
```

Update: 
@Arun was correct about the missing "" on `v1` in the first example. This fixed my example, but I was still having problems with my real code. In the code chunk below, I adapted my example to better reflect my actual code. I chose to create a simpler example at first thinking that the problem was the string `vars`.

Here's an example that does not work :) Uses the same data frame `dat` created above.

```
dv <- colnames(dat)[1]
r2 <- colnames(dat)[2]
# the following loop creates objects r3, r4, r5, and r6
# r5 and r6 are interaction terms
for (v in 3:4) {
  r <- colnames(dat)[v]
  assign(paste("r",v,sep=""),r)
  r <- paste(colnames(dat)[2], colnames(dat)[v], sep="*")
  assign(paste("r",v+2,sep=""),r)
}

# combine r3, r4, r5, and r6 then collapse and remove trailing +
vars2 <- sapply(3:6, function(i) { 
                paste0("r", i, "+")
                })
vars2 <- paste(vars2, collapse = '')
vars2 <- substr(vars2, 1, nchar(vars2)-1)

# concatenate dv, r2 (as a factor), and vars into `eq`
eq <- paste0(dv, " ~ factor(",r2,") +", vars2)
```

Here is the issue:

```
print(eq)
# [1] "v1 ~ factor(v2) +r3+r4+r5+r6"
```

Unlike `regression` in the first example, `eq` does not bring in the column names (e.g., `v3`). The object names (e.g., `r3`) are retained. As such, the following `lm()` command does not work.

```
m2 <- lm(as.formula(eq), data=dat)
```

Comment: I think you mean: `paste0("v1", " ~ ", vars)`.

Comment: thanks, @Arun. You are right. Now my example runs, but I am still getting an error on my real script. Things look to be the same, but I know I must be making an error. I will keep checking and post again if I can figure out the difference.

Comment: In the example you posted, `regressors` is not found. It'd be nice if you could edit your post to provide an example which gives the error now.

Comment: `lm(v1 ~ factor(v2) +r3+r4+r5+r6, data=dat)` doesn't work either.  I think you meant to paste together the contents of `r3` etc rather than the names.

Comment: @Aaron: Yeah, I was not able to figure out how to get `eq` to return the contents of `r3` (i.e., `v3`) etc. `eq` just gives the string `r3+r4+r5+r6`.

Comment: To do that, you'd need `get`.  See edit.  (Though note that other methods are usually preferred to `assign` and `get`.)

Comment: Fantastic, @Aaron. Thanks for the lapply tip. I am slowly giving up loops in favor of apply. Slowly.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I see a couple issues going on here.  First, and I don't think this is causing any trouble, but let's make your data frame in one step so you don't have `v1` through `v4` floating around both in the global environment as well as in the data frame.  Second, let's just make `v2` a factor here so that we won't have to deal with making it a factor later.

```
dat <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(10),
                  v2 = factor(sample(c(0,1), 10, replace=TRUE)),
                  v3 = rnorm(10),
                  v4 = rnorm(10) )
```

**Part One** Now, for your first part, it looks like this is what you want:

```
lm(v1 ~ v2 + v3 + v4, data=dat)
```

Here's a simpler way to do that, though you still have to specify the response variable.

```
lm(v1 ~ ., data=dat)
```

Alternatively, you certainly can build up the function with paste and call `lm` on it.

```
f <- paste(names(dat)[1], "~", paste(names(dat)[-1], collapse=" + "))
# "v1 ~ v2 + v3 + v4"
lm(f, data=dat)
```

However, my preference in these situations is to use `do.call`, which evaluates expressions before passing them to the function; this makes the resulting object more suitable for calling functions like `update` on.  Compare the `call` part of the output.

```
do.call("lm", list(as.formula(f), data=as.name("dat")))
```

**Part Two** About your second part, it looks like this is what you're going for:

```
lm(factor(v2) + v3 + v4 + v2*v3 + v2*v4, data=dat)
```

First, because `v2` is a factor in the data frame, we don't need that part, and secondly, this can be simplified further by better using R's methods for using arithmetical operations to create interactions, like this.

```
lm(v1 ~ v2*(v3 + v4), data=dat)
```

I'd then simply create the function using `paste`; the loop with `assign`, even in the larger case, is probably not a good idea.

```
f <- paste(names(dat)[1], "~", names(dat)[2], "* (", 
           paste(names(dat)[-c(1:2)], collapse=" + "), ")")
# "v1 ~ v2 * ( v3 + v4 )"
```

It can then be called using either `lm` directly or with `do.call`.

```
lm(f, data=dat)
do.call("lm", list(as.formula(f), data=as.name("dat")))
```

**About your code** The problem you had with trying to use `r3` etc was that you wanted the contents of the variable `r3`, not the value `r3`.  To get the value, you need `get`, like this, and then you'd collapse the values together with `paste`.

```
vars <- sapply(paste0("r", 3:6), get)
paste(vars, collapse=" + ")
```

However, a better way would be to avoid `assign` and just build a vector of the terms you want, like this.

```
vars <- NULL
for (v in 3:4) {
  vars <- c(vars, colnames(dat)[v], paste(colnames(dat)[2], 
                                          colnames(dat)[v], sep="*"))
}
paste(vars, collapse=" + ")
```

A more R-like solution would be to use `lapply`:

```
vars <- unlist(lapply(colnames(dat)[3:4], 
                      function(x) c(x, paste(colnames(dat)[2], x, sep="*"))))
```

Comment: Very helpful and educational. Thanks! I'm still unsure about how to get my string to work in the formula, but you've given me an approach that will get me around the problem. Thanks for taking the time to reply. You really helped to clean up my code.

Comment: This was very useful - it helped me understand the `lm` function better.  Shame that `do.call` has such a verbose syntax.

Comment: Meaning that the arguments need to be in a list?  Perhaps, but it makes things like `do.call(rbind, lapply(foo, fun))` slick.

Comment: Stumbled across the Q/A...`do.call` is a function I've always been looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR: use `paste`.

```
create_ctree <- function(col){
    myFormula <- paste(col, "~.", collapse="")
    ctree(myFormula, data)
}
create_ctree("class")
```