# Function to print out regression summary and 5 number summary

Tags: r, function, regression

I am looking for a function that I can input the independent variable and dependent variable and then it will return both the regression summary and a 5 number summary for each of my independent variables. Here is an example and my set up:

```
attach(iris)
five_num=matrix(0,nrow=3,ncol=6)
rownames(five_num)=c('Sepal.Width','Petal.Length','Petal.Width')
colnames(five_num)=c('Min','1st Qu','Median','Mean','3rd Qu','Max')
for (i in 1:3){
  five_num[i,]=summary(eval(parse(text=rownames(five_num)[i])))
}
```

Then I just print the regression and 5 number summaries:

```
summary(lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width,data=iris))
Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, 
    data = iris)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.82816 -0.21989  0.01875  0.19709  0.84570 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.85600    0.25078   7.401 9.85e-12 ***
Sepal.Width   0.65084    0.06665   9.765  < 2e-16 ***
Petal.Length  0.70913    0.05672  12.502  < 2e-16 ***
Petal.Width  -0.55648    0.12755  -4.363 2.41e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3145 on 146 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8586,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8557 
F-statistic: 295.5 on 3 and 146 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16



five_num
 Min 1st Qu Median  Mean 3rd Qu Max
Sepal.Width  2.0    2.8   3.00 3.057    3.3 4.4
Petal.Length 1.0    1.6   4.35 3.758    5.1 6.9
Petal.Width  0.1    0.3   1.30 1.199    1.8 2.5
```

I would like to make a function that looks like this and would return the same thing:

```
reg_5_num=function(dependent,independent){
code here
}
```

The main issue I run into is when I label my independent variables I cannot run them into a regression, because it needs plus signs to work.

In addition, I would like the function to also be able to use interaction term. If my regression is

```
summary(lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width:Petal.Length+Petal.Width,data=iris))

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width:Petal.Length + Petal.Width, 
    data = iris)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.80414 -0.24478 -0.02936  0.25741  0.94391 

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)               4.14976    0.07771  53.397  < 2e-16 ***
Petal.Width              -0.31056    0.11365  -2.733  0.00705 ** 
Sepal.Width:Petal.Length  0.18510    0.01654  11.191  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3524 on 147 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8213,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8189 
F-statistic: 337.8 on 2 and 147 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I would still like to see the same five_num.

Comment: `as.formula(paste(dependent,paste(independent,collapse="+"),sep="~"))`, you can mess around with this to also include interaction terms.

Comment: @Laterow thanks for your response, although I do not see how I can include interaction terms.

Comment: Ok, here's the general breakdown. `lm` accepts objects of the class `formula`. You can create a `formula` by taking a string and using the `as.formula` function. So, this should work: `x=rnorm(10); y=rnorm(10); lm(as.formula("y ~ x"))`. So, the goal is to make a string that fits your formula. I use `paste` to create such a string. Look into the `collapse` and `sep` arguments and what they do. There are also other ways to generate formulas, try google for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use a character string in formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024685/how-to-use-a-character-string-in-formula)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting my independent and dependent variables as inputs, I use a few commands in my function to return the desired output.
    independent='Sepal.Width:Petal.Length+Petal.Width'
    dependent='Sepal.Length'

```
regs=function(independent,dependent) {
summary(lm(as.formula(paste(c(dependent,independent),collapse='~'))))
vars=unlist(strsplit(independent, "[:+]"))
five_num=matrix(0,nrow=length(vars),ncol=6)
rownames(five_num)=vars
colnames(five_num)=c('Min','1st Qu','Median','Mean','3rd Qu','Max')
for (i in 1:length(vars)){
  five_num[i,]=summary(eval(parse(text=vars[i])))
}
print(summary(lm(as.formula(paste(c(dependent,independent),collapse='~')))))
print(five_num)
}
```

This then returns:

```
regs(independent,dependent)

Call:
lm(formula = as.formula(paste(c(dependent, independent), collapse = "~")))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.80414 -0.24478 -0.02936  0.25741  0.94391 

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)               4.14976    0.07771  53.397  < 2e-16 ***
Petal.Width              -0.31056    0.11365  -2.733  0.00705 ** 
Sepal.Width:Petal.Length  0.18510    0.01654  11.191  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3524 on 147 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8213,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8189 
F-statistic: 337.8 on 2 and 147 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

             Min 1st Qu Median  Mean 3rd Qu Max
Sepal.Width  2.0    2.8   3.00 3.057    3.3 4.4
Petal.Length 1.0    1.6   4.35 3.758    5.1 6.9
Petal.Width  0.1    0.3   1.30 1.199    1.8 2.5
```