# pass function arguments by value

Tags: r

I am building models within a function, something along the lines of:

```
some_form <- formula("Species == 'virginica' ~  Petal.Width")
some_fam <- "binomial"
some_fit <- glm(formula = some_form, family = some_fam, data = iris )
```

When I call `summary` on the result, the function call includes the variable names.

```
summary(some_fit) # could also just use some_fit$call
# Returns
# Call:
#   glm(formula = some_form, family = some_fam, data = iris)
```

But I would love to have it return the original (evaluated) formula and family name.  My desired output looks like:

```
# To produce desired output
summary(glm(Species=='virginica' ~ Petal.Width, family = binomial, data = iris))
# Call:
#   glm(formula = Species == "virginica" ~ Petal.Width, family = binomial, data = iris)
#   ^ This is what I want!
```

What I have tried:

```
some_fit <- glm(eval(some_form), family = eval(some_fam), data = iris )
summary(some_fit)
# Returns
# Call:
#   glm(formula = eval(some_form), family = eval(some_fam), data = iris)
```

Replacing the `eval()` with `eval(quote())` or `eval(substitute())` I get a similar result -- the `$call` just copies whatever expression I pass into it.

This might be a basic question (and by all means if it's a duplicate, please flag -- I probably didn't use the right search terms), but I would sincerely appreciate:

1. A basic explanation of how to pass these arguments as values (rather than just references, if that's what I'm currently doing)
2. Any pitfalls in this approach, particularly when executed within a function.

Comment: I'm sure there is a more "correct" way to do this, but `(some_fit <- do.call("glm", args = list(formula = some_form, family = some_fam, data = quote(iris))))`.

Comment: @nrussell I should have thought of that -- a solid answer, if you wish to write it... thanks either way!

Comment: Thanks; but after writing that comment I came across [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024685/how-to-use-a-character-string-in-formula) where Aaron suggests essentially the same approach with a much better explanation, so I'm going to propose this as a duplicate.

Comment: @nrussell thanks.   I figured there was a dupe, but my search terms were too high-level I guess