# How to replace call inside an lm() object?

Tags: r, lm, method-call

In `miceadds::lm.cluster()` the call is represented in this manner `stats::lm(formula = formula, data = data)` and I want to replace it with the actual formula.

For example, there is the function call stored inside an `lm()` object

```
fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, iris)
> fit$call
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = iris)
```

I'm attempting to change it with `call()` with no success so far.

```
fit$call <- call("lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = iris, foo = NULL)")
> fit$call
`lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = iris, foo = NULL)`()
```

There are these ``` `` ``` and the `()` at the end. `class()` yields `call`, though, but it's still not the same as just `lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = iris, foo = NULL)`.

I also tried `formula()` and `reformulate()` but failed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for [`update()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/update.html)?

Comment: To what end? This seems like a step on the way to something that might be better handled another way.

Comment: @Aaron It's concerning `miceadds::lm.cluster()` Please see my edit.

Comment: @r2evans Not really, I explained it in an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it, but we're all still curious why...

The problem you're having is that `call` doesn't take a full function call like you're giving it; instead, just give it the name of the function as the first parameter, and then the parameters you want to use, quoting anything you don't want evaluated.

```
> fit$call <- call("lm", Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, 
                   data=quote("iris"), foo=NULL)
> fit

Call:
lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = "iris", foo = NULL)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  Petal.Length  
      4.3066        0.4089
```

This is what `miceadds` probably should be doing, though with `do.call` to actually execute it; if it were, it would be recording the call as you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17026386/210673 for one example.

You might be able to make your own function that calls `lm.cluster` and does what you want, see below for an example. After looking into it, it would be tricky to fix `lm.cluster`, at least for the `data` piece, the `formula` piece would be an easy fix. For data it's harder to handle because the function could get passed an expression rather than the name of an object.

```
lm.special <- function(formula, data, ... ) {
  lm(formula=formula, data=data, ...)
}

lm.special2 <- function(formula, data.name) {
  cl <- call("lm.special", formula=formula, data=as.name(data.name))
  out <- eval(cl)
  out$call <- cl
  out
}

> lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, iris)

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = iris)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  Petal.Length  
      4.3066        0.4089  

> lm.special(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, iris)

Call:
lm(formula = formula, data = data)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  Petal.Length  
      4.3066        0.4089  

> lm.special2(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, "iris")

Call:
lm.special(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = iris)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  Petal.Length  
      4.3066        0.4089
```

Comment: Works, thanks, even with `miceadds`! Though I couldn't solve the underlying problem with `miceadds` I learned a lot about `call()` today.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to replace a particular component, e.g. the formula:

```
fit$call$formula <- quote(foo ~ bar)
```

If you want to generate `foo ~ bar` programmatically rather than hard-coding it in your script, things get uglier ...