# Box Plot in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, boxplot

I am trying to create/ learn an interactive box plot through Shiny, below id the code i m trying to use. This gives me the error

> Warning: Error in model.frame.default: variable lengths differ (found for 'input$p') 
>     [No stack trace available]

I am unable to figure this out, any help would be much appreciated

CODE:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("p","p",choices = names(mtcars)),
  plotOutput("myplot"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    boxplot(mpg ~ input$p , data=mtcars)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just use `get`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("p","p",choices = names(mtcars)),
  plotOutput("myplot"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    boxplot(mpg ~ get(input$p) , data=mtcars)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: so that means , when ever i am to pick / refer to all the values in a named column in data frame, i need to use get function ?

Answer (score 1):

`boxplot` expect `boxplot(mpg ~ cyl , data=mtcars)` while `input$p` will return a character vector as below

```
Browse[1]> input$p
[1] "mpg"
```

One solution is to use `as.formula`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  #use setdiff to avoid this Error 'Error in .subset2: attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex'
  selectInput("p","p",choices = setdiff(names(mtcars),"mpg")),
  plotOutput("myplot"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    m <- paste0('mpg','~',input$p)
    boxplot(as.formula(m) , data=mtcars)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

To get more explanation/insights see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024685/how-to-use-reference-variables-by-character-string-in-a-formula)

Comment: Thanks A. Suliman, my grip on R is not really great, so for me your solution is kind of complicated. but i am trying to read and understand it

Answer (score 0):

If you have a chance, maybe you want to check out library ggplot2. They have very very nice and easy to use functions and pretty plot.