# Changing the arguments of this function to abstract variables in R

Tags: r

In order to use the *for* loop, I'm trying to replace the arguments in this function by variables:

```
lm(mpg~cylinders, data=Auto)
```

So I did this:

```
var1='cylinders'

lm((paste('mpg ~',var1)), data = Auto)
```

It worked fine.

Now, I wonder how we can replace the arguments cylinders+acceleration by var1 and var2.

So tried the same method. I tried to replace this:

```
lm(mpg~cylinders+acceleration, data=Auto)
```

by

```
var1='cylinders'
var2 = 'acceleration'

lm((paste('mpg ~',var1+var2)), data = Auto)
```

But I got a message error:

```
Error in var1 + var2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

So I want to learn how I can work with var1 and var2 in order to use *for* loop afterwards.

Comment: Do: `(paste('mpg ~',var1,"+",var2))`. Unlike python, you cannot use `+` to directly concat strings, as far as I know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use reference variables by character string in a formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024685/how-to-use-reference-variables-by-character-string-in-a-formula)

Comment: @NelsonGon It worked thank you. The answer of this other question is more general and it will be very helpful. Thanks again

Comment: Please follow the instructions at the top of the  [tag:r] tag page when posting. In particular Auto is not part of base R and no library statements were used so the code is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Use `reformulate` to generate the formula.

```
var1 <- 'cyl'
var2 <- 'disp'
fo <- reformulate(c(var1, var2), "mpg")
lm(fo, mtcars)
```

or you could write it like this which gives the same answer except the above shows literally fo in the Call: line in the output whereas the code below expands fo in the Call: line in the output.

```
do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(mtcars)))
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          cyl         disp  
   34.66099     -1.58728     -0.02058
```